# How to tell if the roots to a quadratic equation is always positive using the quadratic formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Suppose $k>0$ and $(k+1)^2>8k$.

Let:

$\alpha,\beta = \frac{(k+1)/2 \pm \sqrt{(k+1)^2/4-2k}}{2}$

The solution I have says that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ will always be positive.

I don't know how to verify this.

I am especially not sure why the square root term will always be positive and also why it will always be smaller than $\frac{(k+1)}{2}$

Please help.

Comment: The square root is always positive because of your second listed inequality $(k+1)^2 > 8k$. This means that $(k+1)^2/4 > 8k/4 = 2k$.

Comment: @mauna it will be smaller than (k+1)/2 because the term inside the bracket is less than $(k+1)^2$/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$\alpha = \frac{(k+1)/2 + \sqrt{(k+1)^2/4-2k}}{2}$$  $$\beta = \frac{(k+1)/2 - \sqrt{(k+1)^2/4-2k}}{2}$$ be the roots of the quadratic equation. Then $$\alpha +\beta =\frac{k+1}{2} > 0$$ and $$\alpha \beta =\frac{k}{2} >0$$ since $k>0$.